# Lightweight web page rendering

Tags: java, javascript, html, rendering

Given that a HTML page String is available, which contains Javascript links on it to render the dynamic content. Is there a library that can render the HTML "snapshot" (String/Text) of such page?

That is, without using a headless browser like HTMLUnit?

Comment: you looking for something like `wget` or `curl`?

Comment: @Lucas I don't think so. He wants something to run the javascript too, and display the resulted page. And I think there is no such API in Java.

Comment: @DiogoSantana Right I am looking for a library, I've looked at flying-saucer but it seems it can only render HTML + CSS

Comment: Actually I don't need CSS rendering at all